# How can I 'listen' for status changes on an azure durable function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a web app where clients can press a button that calls a durable function. As long as that function is executing, a spinning wheel is animated. When the function finishes executing, I stop/hide the loading wheel, and show a green check-mark.

Currently, I'm just hitting the "statusQueryGetUri" returned by the durable function, on a regular interval, to see if the function is running/stopped.

Is there a way for me to 'listen' for changes in status so I'm not hitting that URL repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

You may follow [this](https://www.fourmoo.com/2020/02/19/how-to-configure-azure-function-app-notifications-for-errors/) link to configure the email/ any notification alert for your azure functions.

You may also check these links for step by step implementation :

http://www.mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-functions-create-an-alert-from-app-insight-to-send-an-email-notification/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log

While you create the alert rule you have an option to select condition:

[image]

There you get "Custom Log Search" as an option:

[image: 25951-image.png]

You can configure the type of trigger or resource on which you want to perform this action while creating the action group:
[image]

You can customize the rule according to your requirement. i.e. you can check for traces log for any execution or you may just check the status of the function. [ this is a reference ]

You may look into these documents for reference:

https://www.fourmoo.com/2020/02/19/how-to-configure-azure-function-app-notifications-for-errors/

http://www.mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-functions-create-an-alert-from-app-insight-to-send-an-email-notification

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a timer-triggered logic app that will do this for you on a recurrent schedule.